# CSS to change background color of fixed header on scroll

Tags: html, css, background-color, parallax

Is there a CSS-only technique to change the background color of a fixed menu bar once the user has scrolled up the page?

Example where color changes from `silver` to `gold`:
https://codepen.io/dpilafian/pen/pwREjR

Below is the JavaScript solution I am currently using:

**HTML**

```html
<body>
   <header>
      <nav>Navigation Bar</nav>
   </header>
   <main>
      <h1>The Main Event</h1>
      <h2>Scroll this page up.</h2>
      <p>Content goes here.</p>
   </main>
   <footer>
      Footer
   </footer>
</body>
```

**CSS (LESS)**

```less
body {
   padding-top: 30px;
   >header, >footer {
      background-color: silver;
      }
   }
body >header {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   transition: all 3s;
   &.scrolled {
      background-color: gold;
      }
   }
```

**JavaScript (with jQuery)**

```js
const elem = $('body >header');
const scrolled = () => {
   const threshold = $(document).scrollTop() > 50;
   elem.toggleClass('scrolled', threshold);
   };
$(window).on({ scroll: scrolled });
```

It would be convenient to replace the above JavaScript solution with some kind of CSS parallax solution if possible.

Comment: Because I am tired, in need of tea, and have to walk my dog soon, I am not going to figure this out any time soon so: it may be possible to hack something together using `position: sticky;` which as far as I know is the only *effective detection* of scrolling we have in CSS. I'll be back.

Comment: I'm all for - CSS instead of JavaScript - when it comes to many things, but in this case, I think JavaScript is the way to deal with events. You may want to do many different things based on information about the page. What does parallax have to do with this?

Comment: @sheriffderek CSS parallax is not triggered by JavaScript events.

Comment: "CSS parallax is not triggered by JavaScript events" - I'm not if this is a statement or an answer. I don't understand why this has the tag `parallax` or `background-color` tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a bit of a hack, place a transparent absolute positioned div with an estimation on the scrolling distance desired translated into `top` coordinates. This would trigger the background change when you scroll to it and hover it.

This is a generic example but you can tweak coordinates and sizes to your benefit (hoverable div has borders just for visual reference).

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

body header,
body footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: silver;
  padding: 10px;
}

body header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 3s;
}

.scrolled {
  background-color: gold;
}

.hoverEffect {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  top: 432px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.hoverEffect:hover+header {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hoverEffect">scroll/hover to this part</div>
<header>
  <nav>Navigation Bar</nav>
</header>
<main>
  <h1>The Main Event</h1>
  <h2>Scroll this page up.</h2>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
</main>
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a CSS-only technique to change the background color of a fixed menu bar once the user has scrolled up the page?

No. There is no way to change rules based on the scroll position with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of bootstrap affix and affix-top, it toggles between the affix and affix-top class based on your scroll. so you can give css to the .affix and .affix-top class based on your need.

Note: affix-top is there when user hasn't scrolled or it scrolls back to top.

Comment: Isn't that really just JavaScript under the hood though?